# Where do I setup django database credentials?

Tags: python, django, pandas, database

I've been trying to upload a pandas dataframe into a django database using `to_sql`, though I see content suggesting that I need to set up some credentials to make it work, such as:

```
from django.conf import settings

user = settings.DATABASES['default']['USER']
password = settings.DATABASES['default']['PASSWORD']
database_name = settings.DATABASES['default']['NAME']
# host = settings.DATABASES['default']['HOST']
# port = settings.DATABASES['default']['PORT']

database_url = 'postgresql://{user}:{password}@localhost:5432/{database_name}'.format(
    user=user,
    password=password,
    database_name=database_name,
)

engine = create_engine(database_url, echo=False)
```

My questions are, wherein django files do I set up those configurations `user`, `password`, and `database_name`? and is there a way to not expose sensitive data such as `user` and `password`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use yaml, yml, env, etc. The best approach I find is using environment variables. For Django, you can use Django-environ. Link is below:

https://django-environ.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Remember: You can also create different environment for production and development. And do not push your production environment in git.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but where do I set up those credentials? Is it at the settings.py file of the django project?

Comment: Yes. First create .env file. Then import credentials in settings.py. By doing this, you can get your credentials from settings.py. For example: from django.conf import settings. It will be helpful. Otherwise you need to import credentials from env from all views if you need to use.